# Case in Where clause not working properly on Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Can anybody please tell me what is wrong with my query. I know for sure it is something wrong with my case statement inside where clause for sure. Without the Case statement, this query will run fine.

Error – SELECT Failed. 3707:Syntax error, expected something like an ‘END keyword between ‘)’ and “>=”

```
SELECT 
    mp.chnl_name AS mp_channel,
    fsk.sku_prod_id AS pro_id,
    fsk.dateint  AS avlbl_dt,
    fsk.sku_num AS sku,
    fsk.upc_txt AS UPC,
    Coalesce(fsk.brand_name,'N/A') AS brand,
    fsk.ruckload AS LTL_Flag,
    fsk.price_amt AS item_selling_price,
    fsk.on_hand_unit_qty AS qoh,
    fsk.netpropt AS profite,
    (fsk.price_amt  + fsk.shpg_amt) AS lms,
    (GP)*100 AS net_pct
FROM EDW.ITEM_AVLBL mp
JOIN EDW.FULL_SKU fsk ON mp.item_id = fsk.item_id
JOIN  EDW.SHORT_SKU ssk ON ssk.sh_sku_id = fsk.sh_sku_id
WHERE 1=1
    AND mp.chnl_name  LIKE '%google%'  ---------- This is a prompt but I hard coded to test
    AND fsk.item_create_dt >=  '2019-10-20'
    AND  net_pct >= 10
    AND CASE WHEN mp.chnl_name  = 'CA_FACEBOOK'  THEN  ((GP)*100)  >= 7 ELSE  fsk.first_cost > 500 END
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,fsk.first_cost
```

Can anybody please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Use AND/OR constructions instead. Much easier to optimize.

Comment: @jarlh  I only need my case condition to work when it Facebook. That is why I put the case condition. Any idea why I am getting an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case does not work in where here, you can re-write to use ANDs and ORs

```
AND ( (mp.chnl_name  = 'CA_FACEBOOK' AND ((GP)*100)  >= 7 ) 
    OR (mp.chnl_name  != 'CA_FACEBOOK' AND fsk.first_cost > 500) )
```

---

according to what you said below add the following to the where:

```
AND ( (mp.chnl_name  = 'CA_FACEBOOK' AND ((GP)*100)  >= 7 AND fsk.first_cost > 500)
      OR mp.chnl_name  != 'CA_FACEBOOK'
    )
```

Comment: I only need this condition when it equal to Facebook. That why it is in a case condition. Does this work the way I want it? Usually, they insert Google, twitter other than Facebook. If it is google or twitter case condition should to effect my report.  Does it make sense?

Comment: I need both conditions when the only  mp.chnl_name  = 'CA_FACEBOOK'

Comment: @WeldaSudha -  this is the same logic as the case condition  If you have different logic then you should explain what it is.

Comment: May  be I confused you guys. All I need is when they enter Facebook (they can enter google, twitter, etc prompt) then my `  ((GP)*100)  >= 7` and ` fsk.first_cost > 500` and this is an additional filter criteria for Facebook .  I tried like below, its works but when we enter google like in code `mp.chnl_name  LIKE '%google%'` it give me nothing. 
`HAVING
    (CASE WHEN mp.chnl_name  = 'CA_FACEBOOK'  AND  ((GP)*100)  >= 7 THEN  1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 
    AND(CASE WHEN mp.chnl_name  = 'CA_FACEBOOK' AND  fsk.first_cost > 500 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1`

Comment: so @WeldaSudha if they enter facebook but don't have those values then you want to not include those results?  if so then you don't need a case.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. When they have 0 values it is going to be a problem. I think I just ran into that problem today. Any way to fix that, what I am trying to do something similar to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `CASE`:

```
( (mp.chnl_name = 'CA_FACEBOOK'  AND  ((GP)*100)  >= 7) OR
  (mp.chnl_name <> 'CA_FACEBOOK' AND fsk.first_cost > 500)
)
```

The problem is that Teradata does not support returning a boolean type from a `CASE` expression.  Hence, your comparisons in the `THEN` clauses are not understood syntactically.

EDIT:

Based on your comment, the logic you want is:

```
( (mp.chnl_name = 'CA_FACEBOOK'  AND  ((GP)*100)  >= 7 AND fsk.first_cost > 500
  ) OR
  (mp.chnl_name <> 'CA_FACEBOOK' )
)
```

Comment: You're missing a `)`

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I only need this condition when it equal to Facebook. That why it is in a case condition. Does this work the way I want it. Usually, they insert Google, twitter other than Facebook. If it is google or twitter case condition should to effect my report.  Does it make sense?

Comment: Guys,  ((GP)*100)  >= 7) and fsk.first_cost > 500 should only work when it equal to Facebook, and I need both conditions. When mp.chnl_name equal to something else (Google or Twitter) it should not affect my report. Does it make sense? The above two answers does not work for me.

Comment: @WeldaSudha . . . That is not what your `case` expression is trying to do.  It is testing `GP` for facebook and `first_cost` when not Facebook.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , Sorry If I confuse you.  All I trying to do is when somebody type or filter facebook, I need `GP` should be greater than 7 and `first_cost` should be greater than 500 . This should only affect for when using Facebook. Any other filter (search term like google or twitter)  should not affect this condition. Any idea how to archive this?

Comment: @Hogan I edited my answer to fix the error when I have 0. But It does not look good. Is there any other professional way I can get this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want:

```
WHERE 
  (mp.chnl_name <> 'CA_FACEBOOK' 
    AND mp.chnl_name  LIKE '%google%'  ---------- This is a prompt but I hard coded to test
    AND fsk.item_create_dt >=  '2019-10-20'
    AND  net_pct >= 10
OR (( mp.chnl_name  = 'CA_FACEBOOK' AND GP*100  >= 7 AND fsk.first_cost > 500))
```

But if you're creating this WHERE-condition in your application (the `1=1` seems to indicate this) you better apply your logic there.

Comment: does this work when I enter google on `mp.chnl_name`? I only need an addition filter to Facebook only.  Something like below, but it does not work. 
`HAVING
 (CASE WHEN mp.chnl_name  = 'CA_FACEBOOK'  AND  ((GP)*100)  >= 7 THEN  1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 
 AND(CASE WHEN mp.chnl_name  = 'CA_FACEBOOK' AND  fsk.first_cost > 500 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1`

Comment: Your explanantions are totally confusing. And why are you using HAVING?

Comment: I only need this filter which is `mp.chnl_name  = 'CA_FACEBOOK'`. If you look at my 'WHERE 1=1
    AND mp.chnl_name  LIKE '%google%'  ---------- This is a prompt but I hard coded to test' ` this can change to any other terms. Now it only give me `mp.chnl_name  = 'CA_FACEBOOK'` it does not give me anything else. Does it make sense? i can come up with a clear idea if not. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments that the original ELSE condition is supposed to be ANDed instead:

```
SELECT 
    mp.chnl_name AS mp_channel,
    fsk.sku_prod_id AS pro_id,
    fsk.dateint  AS avlbl_dt,
    fsk.sku_num AS sku,
    fsk.upc_txt AS UPC,
    Coalesce(fsk.brand_name,'N/A') AS brand,
    fsk.ruckload AS LTL_Flag,
    fsk.price_amt AS item_selling_price,
    fsk.on_hand_unit_qty AS qoh,
    fsk.netpropt AS profite,
    (fsk.price_amt  + fsk.shpg_amt) AS lms,
    (GP)*100 AS net_pct
FROM EDW.ITEM_AVLBL mp
JOIN EDW.FULL_SKU fsk ON mp.item_id = fsk.item_id
JOIN  EDW.SHORT_SKU ssk ON ssk.sh_sku_id = fsk.sh_sku_id
WHERE 1=1
    AND (mp.chnl_name  LIKE '%google%'  ---------- This is the prompt value
    AND fsk.item_create_dt >=  '2019-10-20'
    AND  net_pct >= 10
    AND (mp.chnl_name  <> 'CA_FACEBOOK' -- if not Facebook, don't care ORed terms
         OR (GP*100  >= 7 AND fsk.first_cost > 500))
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 /* ,fsk.first_cost */
```

I don't think you want to GROUP BY first_cost. And this implicitly assumes mp.chnl_name is not NULL, so it's either equal to CA_FACEBOOK or not equal. If NULLs are allowed, you would need to explicitly check that condition also, e.g. `(mp.chnl_name <> 'CA_FACEBOOK' OR mp.chnl_name IS NULL)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works me, but I probably confused you guys in the description. Thank you so much for the quick respond tho. I really appreciate your help and time.

```
AND (CASE WHEN mp.sls_trans_web_orgn_chnl_name  = 'CA_FACEBOOK'  AND   fsk.full_sku_unit_first_cost  <  500 AND  (juice/NullIfZero(gms))*100  >= 7 THEN 1 
  WHEN mp.sls_trans_web_orgn_chnl_name  <> 'CA_FACEBOOK'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) = 1
```

Comment: this is wrong --- what about cases where first_cost > 0 and chnl_name is not facebook --- those will be filtered out.

Comment: @Hogan I edited my answer to fix the error when I have 0. But It does not look good. Is there any other professional way I can get this? I want to change the long case statement.   Thank you

Comment: Yes -- I updated my answer to solve your problem -- you don't need case, instead you use OR -- see the edited new part of my answer

Comment: @Hogan Thank you so much for the help and kindness. This took me two days to honest. I really appreciate your help.  You are awesome!!